# Is there any parameter to control the timeout of CLOSE_WAIT connection status on Windows server?

Tags: windows, windows-7, tcp

I've got a lot of **`CLOSE_WAIT`** connections on **`Windows server`**, is there any good way to speed that `CLOSE_WAIT` disappear, such as config one parameter in the registry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CLOSE_WAIT isn't a timed-out condition. It means that the peer has closed the connection and the host is waiting for the local application to close this end. In other words it indicates an application bug: a socket leak.